# create SQL function for H2 database on liquibase

Tags: sql, h2, liquibase, sql-function

Since I need to use 2 databases (psql and h2) with liquibase I tried to create SQL functions in different ways:

```
<changeSet author="zina" id="calculate_test">
        <sqlFile            dbms="h2, psql"
                            encoding="UTF-8"
                            endDelimiter="/nGO"
                            path="calculate_test.sql"
                            relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                            splitStatements="false"
                            stripComments="false"/>
    </changeSet>
```

where the **calculate_test.sql** looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate()
RETURNS int
BEGIN
RETURN 5;
END;

GO
```

OR using sql code directly in

```
<changeSet author="xxx" id="sql-example">
    <sql dbms="h2"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"
            splitStatements="true"
            stripComments="true">xxx</sql>
</changeSet>
```

and get the same error.

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set migrations.xml::calculate_test::zkensche:
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE OR 

REPLACE FUNCTION[*] CALCULATE()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
RETURN 5;
END;

GO"; expected "FORCE, VIEW, ALIAS, SEQUENCE, USER, TRIGGER, ROLE, SCHEMA, CONSTANT, DOMAIN, TYPE, DATATYPE, AGGREGATE, LINKED, MEMORY, CACHED, LOCAL, GLOBAL, TEMP, TEMPORARY, TABLE, SYNONYM, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, HASH, SPATIAL, INDEX"; SQL statement: ...
```

Have anybody managed to create a SQL function on H2 or is it the only way to write it on Java?

According to [documentation](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html) there is no create **CREAT FUNCTION** SQL command.

I'll be thankful for comments, workarounds and Java snippets.

Best,
Zina

Comment: h2 only supports functions written in Java, not in a procedural SQL language. If you do need that, you might want to consider using HSQLDB instead

Answer (score 0):

In order to create similar to function object in H2 you need to use "CREATE ALIAS ..." expression. The function basically Java code.

Here is the example of mockup call of the procedure which should return a JSON in a form of text:

```
    CREATE ALIAS gen_pageGlobal AS $$
String nextPrime(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4) {
    return "{\"type\" : \"page\", \"data\" : {\"rn\": 1, \"email\": \"admin@gmail.com\", \"projectCount\": 6}}";
}
$$;
```

Please keep in mind in order to create a liquibase it is essential to set proper `endDelimiter = "$$"`:

```
<changeSet id="20231219070000-4-2" author="java" context="dev">
    <sql dbms="h2" endDelimiter="$$">
        DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS gen_pageGlobal;
        CREATE ALIAS gen_pageGlobal AS $$
        String nextPrime(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4) {
            return "{\"data\": []}";
        }
        $$;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```